# Wordpress - Facebook SDK - Comments Plugin Loads in Staging but not in Production

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

We are trying to use the Facebook SDK to engage users. We have a simple Facebook App on our blog that allows users to "sign in" with Facebook as well as "Comment" on articles etc. On our staging site, loading the Facebook SDK asynchronously, we have this functionality working normally, users can sign in with Facebook and Comment on posts. However, on the production site which is using the exact same Wordpress theme files and Wordpress App ID, the Comments only load SOMETIMES (1/10 times). Here is the code in "Header.php" that I am using to access the Facebook SDK in both the staging and production. Much of my code was taken from the Facebook SDK "Sign in with Facebook" Instructions. As you can see, I have already tried using FB.XFBML.parse(); to reload the XFBML but it doesn't make any differnce. Any help anyone can give me as to why the Comments plugin loads in Staging and Production would be much appreciated.

```
<script>window.isSigned = 0;
    ////////////FB LOGIN STUFF////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response.status);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // You are logged into your app and Facebook.
      document.getElementById('fbinfoz').innerHTML = '1'
      testAPI();


  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('fbinfoz').innerHTML = '0'
      /*document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into this app.';*/

  } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('fbinfoz').innerHTML = '0'
      /*document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into Facebook.';*/

  }
}

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
});

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
};

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email,age_range,birthday,gender,locale,timezone,picture', function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            var fbname = response.name;
            console.log('First Name: ' + response.first_name);
            var fbfname = response.first_name;
            console.log('Last Name: ' + response.last_name);
            var fblname = response.last_name;
            console.log('Email: ' + response.email);
            var fbemail = response.email;
            console.log('FB ID: ' + response.id);
            var fbid = response.id;
            console.log('Age Range Min: ' + response.age_range.min);
            var fbagerange = response.age_range.min;
            console.log('Birthday: ' + response.birthday);
            console.log('Gender: ' + response.gender);
            var fbgender = response.gender;
            console.log('Locale: ' + response.locale);
            var fblocale = response.locale;
            console.log('Timezone: ' + response.timezone);
            var fbtimezone = response.timezone;
            console.log('Picture: http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id +'/picture?type=large');
            var fbpicture = 'Picture: http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id +'/picture?type=large';


        /* document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';*/
    });
});
}
</script>
```

And the Comments Section:

```
<script>
  FB.XFBML.parse();
</script>
    <div id="facebookCommentz" style="" class="fb-comments" data-width="100%" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would share what ultimately fixed this problem. Our Staging site and Production site were both using the same Facebook App ID. The Staging site was set up with a .htaccess redirect that forwards all other IPs except ours to the Production site.  We were testing the Facebook Comments plugin on the Staging site by adding Comments to staging pages, but those same live pages on the Production site would not gain the comments. I simply created a new Facebook App with a new App ID and everything works normally.

So, I guess the answer is: **It's best to have two different Facebook App ID's for Staging and Production.**